# Hashtable: Only saving the last element added

Tags: java, hashtable

Whenever I create multiple students, add them to the studentclass Hashtable, and try to print the hashtable(or perform any action on it) it only holds the last Student entered.

EX: Created Students: John Taylor, Timmy Turner, Optimus Prime
PrintHastable: {6=Optimus Prime ,4=Optimus Prime, 2=Optimus Prime}

How can I get the hashtable to hold all entered values as opposed to just the last one?

School Class
public class School{

```
//static Long counter = (long) 1;
public Hashtable<Long, Student> studentclass;


public  void addStudent() {
    
    studentclass = new Hashtable<Long, Student>(); 
    boolean addanotherstudent = true;
    long counter = TestMain.counter;
    
    Student theStudent = new Student();

    
    while(addanotherstudent) {

        String fname = "";
        while(fname.length() <=0) {
        Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("What is your first name? ");
        fname = key.next();
        theStudent.setfname(fname);
        }

        String lname = "";
        while(lname.length() <=0) {
        Scanner key1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("What is your last name? ");
        lname = key1.nextLine();
        theStudent.setlname(lname);
        }

        double grade = -1;
        while(grade < 0 || grade > 4) {
        Scanner key2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("What is your GPA (0 - 4)? ");
        grade = key2.nextDouble();
        theStudent.setgrade(grade);
        }

        long accountId = counter++;
        String studentId = fname + lname + accountId;
        
        theStudent.setsid(studentId);
        theStudent.setaid(accountId);
        
        
        counter++;
        //Student theStudents = new Student();
        studentclass.put(counter, theStudent);
        
        
        Scanner ask =  new  Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Do  you want to  add another student?(y or n) ");
        String ans = ask.nextLine();
        
        if(ans.charAt(0) == 'y' || ans.charAt(0) == 'Y') {
            
            continue;
            
            
        }else {
            
            addanotherstudent = false;
            
        }
    
}

}
```

TestMain Class

```
public class TestMain {

static long counter = 0;

//public static Hashtable<Long, Student> studentclass;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    //studentclass = new Hashtable<Long, Student>(); 
    
    School GSU = new School();
    
    GSU.addStudent();       
    
    GSU.filterStudent(3);

    System.out.println(GSU.studentclass);
    
    

    
}
```

}

Student Class

```
public class Student {

private  String fname;
private  String lname;
private  String sid;
private  long aid;
private double grade;

public void setfname(String setfname) {
    
    fname = setfname;
    
}

public String getfname() {
    
    return fname;
}


public void setlname(String setlname) {
    
    lname = setlname;

}

public String getlname() {
    
    return lname;
    
}

public void setsid(String setsid) {
    
    sid = setsid;

}

public String getsid() {
    
    return sid;
    
}

public void setaid(long setaid) {
    
    aid = setaid;

}

public long getaid() {
    
    return  aid;
    
}

public void setgrade(double setgrade) {
    
    grade = setgrade;

}

public double getgrade() {
    
    return  grade;
    
}

public String toString() {
    
    
    return fname + " " + lname;
    
    
    
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? What is your problem?

Comment: The getter and setter methods in Student class should not be static. Inside the add student method you should create an object of Student and set the fields. Then put the object into the hashtable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of things that are wrong about your approach.

- You are initializing variables incorrectly in the Student class constructor.
- You have made all the variables and methods in Student class static. So for every new Student you create, you will be reusing the same variables.

Many more improvements can be made on this code. But I am adding a quick fix here.

**TestMain.java**

```java
public class TestMain {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        addStudent();
    }


    private static Long counter = (long) 1;
    private static Hashtable<Long, Student> studentclass = new Hashtable<Long, Student>();

    public static void addStudent() {

        boolean addanotherstudent = true;
        while (addanotherstudent) {
            String fname = "";
            while (fname.length() <= 0) {
                Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.print("What is your first name? ");
                fname = key.next();
            }

            String lname = "";
            while (lname.length() <= 0) {
                Scanner key1 = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.print("What is your last name? ");
                lname = key1.nextLine();
            }

            double grade = -1;
            while (grade < 0 || grade > 4) {
                Scanner key2 = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.print("What is your GPA (0 - 4)? ");
                grade = key2.nextDouble();
            }

            long accountId = counter;
            String studentId = fname + lname + accountId;

            Student student = new Student(fname, lname, studentId, accountId, grade);
            studentclass.put(counter, new Student(fname, lname, studentId, accountId, grade));

            counter++;

            Scanner ask = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Do  you want to  add another student?(y or n) ");
            String ans = ask.nextLine();
            if (ans.charAt(0) == 'y' || ans.charAt(0) == 'Y') {

                continue;


            } else {

                addanotherstudent = false;

            }

        }
        System.out.println(studentclass);
    }
}
```

**Student.java**

```java
public class Student {
    private String fname;
    private String lname;
    private String sid;
    private long aid;
    private double grade;

    public Student(String fname, String lname, String sid, long aid, double grade) {
        this.fname = fname;
        this.lname = lname;
        this.sid = sid;
        this.aid = aid;
        this.grade = grade;
    }

    public String getFname() {
        return fname;
    }

    public void setFname(String fname) {
        this.fname = fname;
    }

    public String getLname() {
        return lname;
    }

    public void setLname(String lname) {
        this.lname = lname;
    }

    public String getSid() {
        return sid;
    }

    public void setSid(String sid) {
        this.sid = sid;
    }

    public long getAid() {
        return aid;
    }

    public void setAid(long aid) {
        this.aid = aid;
    }

    public double getGrade() {
        return grade;
    }

    public void setGrade(double grade) {
        this.grade = grade;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student{" +
                "fname='" + fname + '\'' +
                ", lname='" + lname + '\'' +
                ", sid='" + sid + '\'' +
                ", aid=" + aid +
                ", grade=" + grade +
                '}';
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem has nothing to do with `HashTable`.

Your `Student` class has two critical errors:

1. You made all its member `static` which means they exist only once - new variables are not create when you create new instance of this class.
   Calling `new Stident` will do nothing for you, you will always overwrite any previous data.
2. Your constructor has the assignments backwards:
   Instead of storing values passed in constructor parameters in class members you do the opposite!
   You store contents of class members in parameters, basically throwing all your data in to the trash bin.

You must fix both problems for your program to work!

Answer (score 1):

Because all the instance variables for the student are static, each time you set them, the value is class-wide... that is all instances share the same values you set. Each time you iterate, and update the value of `fname` say, all instances get updated, as they all share the same field value. If you had two instances and updated the first name of one "instance" you'd be updating all others simultaneously. You need to remove all the keywords `static` from `Student` class.